# FaceTime volume issue in Mavericks

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio, osx-mavericks, facetime

We have an audio application for Mac OSX which is music player with some audio effects . Ever since we upgraded to mavericks(10.9) we are finding one weird issue i.e when we get call from facetime our application volume automatically reduces. As per our analysis,facetime seems to lower every other applications volume and there is no control on it.
These are few discussion on the same issue
https://discussions.apple.com/message/23592588#23592588

As a temporary fix , we are planing to display some kind of UI to the user to inform that volume is reduced due to the facetime call.

Is there any notifications/API that we will get when we receive a facetime call or any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: We have contacted apple and they asked us to report bug in apple radar.

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the audio ducking only fixes the reduced sound that occurs when the "voice" of your computer is speaking. If you have set it up to do so, it is not a fix for the facetime and other application's issue

Answer (score -6):

This is called audio ducking. There is a setting for this built into Mavericks. Open "System Preferences". Go to "Accessibility". Go to "VoiceOver". Click on "Open VoiceOver Utility...". Go to "Sound". The box for "Enable audio ducking" should be checked. Click on this box to uncheck it, and the audio ducking should no longer occur.

Comment: Not working for you is not enough for a down vote, so fixing that... on the other hand, it does suck (I have the same problem).